# CLI method for vlookup like search

Tags: regex, bash, unix, awk, grep

I have a huge csv file, demo.csv (few GBs in size) which has 3 columns like the following:

```
$ cat demo.csv
call_start_time,called_no,calling_no
43284.85326,1111111111,2222222222
43284.83192,3333333333,1111111111
43284.83205,2222222222,1111111111
43284.81304,4444444444,3333333333
```

I am trying to find the rows which has repeated values in either column 2 or 3 (whatever the order). For example, this should be the output for the data shown above:

```
call_start_time,called_no,calling_no
43284.85326,1111111111,2222222222
43284.83205,2222222222,1111111111
```

I tried to use csvkit:

```
csvsql --query "select called_no, calling_no, call_start_time, count(1) from file123 group by called_no,calling_no having count(1)>1" file123.csv > new.csv
```

Comment: Consider adding your effort to resolve the same issue .

Comment: The second and fourth rows both have repeating values, why are they not matched?

Comment: I was trying to use csvkit:
`csvsql --query "select called_no, calling_no, call_start_time, count(1) from file123 group by called_no,calling_no having count(1)>1" file123.csv > new.csv`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness: If we consider 2nd row, it would have been a match if there were any other rows with 3333333333 in called_no & 1111111111 in calling_no or vice versa. Since there are no repeats, hence no match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$ awk '
    NR==1 { print; next }
    { key = ($2>$3 ? $2 FS $3 : $3 FS $2) }
    seen[key]++ { print orig[key] $0; delete orig[key]; next }
    { orig[key] = $0 ORS }
' file
call_start_time called_no   calling_no
43284.85326     1111111111  2222222222
43284.83205     2222222222  1111111111
```

Comment: Sorry for posting the data in wrong format. The source file is actually comma separated. I have edited my post. Sorry once again. Can you please help in modifying the awk you suggested?

Comment: Add `BEGIN{FS=OFS=","}` at the start of the script.

Comment: Only the headers in the [output](https://imgur.com/a/IjULMBx). I am using cygwin btw.

Comment: run dos2unix on your input and try again. If that still fails it means there's something else different about your input compared to whats posted in your question and you'll have to investigate what that is yourself.

Comment: Yes. It's perfect now. Thanks so much for staying with me the entire time.

Answer (score 1):

With awk you can build an associative array `a` with records as values and keys `k` build with the fields $2 and $3 sorted and joined with a pipe.

```
awk -F, 'NR==1; { k=($3<$2) ? $3"|"$2 : $2"|"$3; if (a[k]) { if (a[k]!="#") {print a[k];a[k]="#"} print} else a[k]=$0}' file
```

If the current record has a key that already exists, the stored record is printed (only if it is the first time) and the current record is printed too.

Comment: I tried using the awk you suggested and got an output. But when I try to search the main file with either the called_no or calling_no received in the awk output, I only get entries which are single i.e they are not repeated in any order.

Comment: @ArijitBanerjee: I tested it with your posted data and it works. Are you sure the sample in your question is representative of your real data?

Comment: We already have SUBSEP, FS, OFS, and RS available and highly unlikely to be present in the fields to separate the array indices, don't introduce some new strings that we also need to hope won't  be present, e.g. `"|"`.and `"#"`. Also, use `if (k in a)` instead of `if (a[k])` to test for `a[k]` being populated so it won't fail if/when `a[k]` evaluates numerically to zero.

Comment: @EdMorton: I don't hope anything, columns are filled with numbers, so introducing a pipe or using a sharp isn't a problem. `if (a[k])` isn't a problem too since even if the three numerical fields are set to zero, it works (other kind of records that may be evaluated to zero are not interesting and there's no need to store them).

Comment: I understand with the same data provided the script will behave as expected but you could write the code as concisely using more robust constructs and then it'd work in the general case with other data. There's just no reason to write code that will only work for specific data when you can write very slightly different code that'll work for any data and is just as easy to write and if you get into the habit of writing the robust code then you won't get bitten by unexpected input data some day.

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: Sorry for posting the data in wrong format. The source file is actually comma separated. I have edited my post. Sorry once again. Can you please help in modifying the awk you suggested?

Comment: @ArijitBanerjee: in this case, start the command like this: `awk -F, '...`

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: I executed this `$ awk -F, 'NR==1; { k=($3<$2) ? $3"|"$2 : $2"|"$3; if (a[k]) { if (a[k]!="#") {print a[k];a[k]="#"} print} else a[k]=$0}' demo.csv` but got an output with only the headers `call_start_time,called_no,calling_no`. Here is the [demo.csv](https://ufile.io/f62ws)

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte: It was the dos2unix that was the problem. Thanks. Your awk is perfect.